# How to get the NAME and value of a radio button when DYNAMICALLY selected - in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two groups of radio buttons here and I want to get the content of Name and Value attributes when they're dynamically selected. I did get the content of the value attribute but not the name attribute.
Appreciate your help!
Here's the code:

```js
var var1 = "";

function myFun(){
$( "input[type=radio]:checked" ).each(function(){
 var1 = $(this).val();
 alert(var1);
});
}
```

```html
<form>
<h3>Fruits</h3>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="orange" id="orange">
    <label for="orange">orange</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="apple" id="apple">
    <label for="apple">apple</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="banana" id="banana">
    <label for="banana">banana</label>
  </div>

<h3>Delivery</h3>
    <div> 
    <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="Y" id="y">
    <label for="orange">Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="N" id="n">
    <label for="apple">No</label>
  </div>

  <button onclick="myFun()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var var1 = "";

function myFun(){
$( "input[type=radio]:checked" ).each(function(){
 var1 = $(this).val();
 var2 = $(this).attr("name");
 alert(var1);
        alert(var2);
});
}
```

```html
<form>
<h3>Fruits</h3>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="orange" id="orange">
    <label for="orange">orange</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="apple" id="apple">
    <label for="apple">apple</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="banana" id="banana">
    <label for="banana">banana</label>
  </div>

<h3>Delivery</h3>
    <div> 
    <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="Y" id="y">
    <label for="orange">Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="N" id="n">
    <label for="apple">No</label>
  </div>

  <button onclick="myFun()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the name attribute with `this.name`:

```
var var1 = "";
function myFun() {
    $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function () {
        var1 = $(this).val();
        var2 = this.name;
        console.log(var1,var2);
    });
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Lad0hwss/)**

Comment: Thank you ! 
That was correct. But I confirmed @Luka's answer for encouragement. 
Appreciate your kindness.

Answer (score 2):

Hummm, this ? :

```
$(this).attr("name")
```

Comment: Thank you ! 
That was correct. But I confirmed @Luka's answer for encouragement. 
Appreciate your kindness.

Answer (score -1):

you could also do it on a change event when you want to trigger after a user has checked or unchecked a radiobutton and
you can get the name attr by using jquery .attr function:

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
});
```

you can also check it the radio button is checked or not by

```
if($(this).is(':checked')){
    console.log('is_checked');
}
```